# Novel with plane which is soundless and can't see while in sky

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel during my childhood which is a science fiction novel. Villain uses a lot of complicated weapons. He has a plane which can fly without being noticed. It doesn't make any noise and while in sky it cant be seen. In between hero get hold of one of those plane. Villain lives in fortress or something inside a jungle.

The novel has more than two parts. I read almost all parts, but was unable to read final parts. I read them 15 years ago. I would like to read them all again. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Note: I read the translated version of novel. I don't remember who wrote it in which language originally.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the level of technology? Like is it golden-age stuff with vacuum tubes, transistors, or mysterious alloys? Or is it more modern-day technology?

Answer (score 2):

Just to rule out potentially obvious answers, this wouldn't be Jules Vernes's *[Robur the Conqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robur_the_Conqueror)*, would it? That involves a villain (a relatively benevolent one, really) who terrorizes the nations with his superior airship which was indeed relatively soundless. There was a sequel, *The Master of the World*. Robur isn't noted as living in a jungle, but they do make a stopover in the Chatham Islands, which I do not believe is in the midst of civilized territory. And, near the end, there's a climactic air battle between the protagonist and Robur in their respective airships.

There's a longish list of fictional aircraft on Wikipedia. Closest match I've found for what you've described is the third book in the [Patrick McLanahan series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_McLanahan#Patrick_McLanahan_Series) (most famous for *Flight of the Old Dog*), *Night of the Hawk* where a Russian general has a stealth bomber and the good guys wind up stealing it and spiriting it off for analysis. There were many books in the series, so it's possible that you had them introduced to you in a more jumbled version, or as if the third book were independent of other books in the series. *[Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_%28novel%29)* is a standalone novel, so that seems unlikely, but I'll mention it in case it sparks a memory.

Comment: No this isn't one. The novel I read has more than 2 parts. Story doesn't sound familiar

Comment: By "more than two parts", do you mean that it was released in multiple volumes? If so, were each of them a full novel size (over a hundred pages) or were they released as novellas or as chapters?

Comment: Yes they were multiple volumes with more than 100 pages.